# How to display local pdf file using google reader in android app?

Tags: android, pdf, local

I want to load a pdf file stored in my assets using google reader. This is what I am trying to do:

Uri file= Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/ganesh.pdf");
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,"" +    "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" + file + "&embedded=true"  + " alt=\"pageNo\" width=\"100%\" height=\"80%\">", "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

The google reader is not able to find the document in above case. However, if I use following "url" instead of "file", it displays the specified document.

String url = "http://www.mysite.com/pdf2/ganesh.pdf";

Thanks in advance!

Comment: U need to integrate third party libraries like http://www.mupdf.com/

Comment: What I gather from your comment is that Google reader will work only http protocol for input document. If so, I will discard the option of using Google reader in my app.

Comment: What I gather from your comment is that Google reader works only on http protocol for document. If so, I will discard the option of using Google reader. As another option, I tried using mupdf in my app (ref: How to use MuPDF with your EXISTING Eclipse project - http://pastebin.com/YzHUhzE7). I completed the integration, but failed on the last step ("call up com.artifex.mupdf.ChoosePDFActivity.class in your application. This is the main class for MuPDF."). I am new to Android development. Can you provide me an appropriate link that would teach me how to integrate mupdf lib in an android app.